# Why can' t ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{7, 8}], 4] return results

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 12.1**

`ChromaticPolynomial` is new in 10.0

---

Why can' t `ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{7, 8}], 4]` return results?

```
    ChromaticPolynomial[CycleGraph[8], 4]
    ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{7, 8}], z]
    ChromaticPolynomial[
     GridGraph[{7, 8}], 4] (*Maple can solve this problem*)
```

But Maple can solve this problem.
And, `ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{5, 6}], z]` can give a result.

[image]

Comment: It looks like something you should report to Wolfram Support.

Comment: Same thing reported here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1695967

Comment: `ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{7, 8}], z]` followed by `ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{6, 7}], z]` **crashes** my kernel (V12, MacOS) but `ChromaticPolynomial[GridGraph[{6, 7}], z]` in a fresh kernel computes without problem.